# why is the gc root of byte array itself in mat?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, dalvik, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I has this case: byte array was marked gc root in MAT when I analyse android heap. I has done exclude weak/soft reference to gc root. the screenshot like this:

[image]

it is means byte array is gc root? It is hard to convince.

Could you can explain this phenomenon?

This is same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943431/android-memory-leak-ema-suspect-byte-loaded-by-system-class-loader), but no one explain it.

I guess that the native has a reference to byte array, but I don't have enough knowledge to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Eh, If you expand the Class Name column , you will find "Native Stack" in the end.

[image]

It is because Native Stack quote the byte array. If you read the Bitmap create source code, you will found byte array is allocated in native. [Bitmap_creator](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/Bitmap.cpp#712)